# Visual Studio 2008 Debug is launching my .NET WPF app with old source files

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

This started happening randomly yesterday.

When I press F5 to test my project, an old build of the program (circa yesterday afternoon) launches.  No changes (and I've tried in a few different files) are reflected in the project.

However, and this is truly perplexing, if I go to Build --> Build from the Menu bar, the output .exe in the /bin/release/ directory DOES include all the recent changes.

What could possibly be causing this?

*** Update***

To be more specific, changes to my .vb files are being reflected, but changes in my XAML documents are not.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly, and I'm not sure how, I ended up with a copy of the OBJ folder in a subfolder of my project (called "Misc", here I was keeping misc. files)

I deleted that, and now it's working fine.  I haven't the faintest idea why this would fix the issue, but it's the only thing I changed in all this exploration.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the Modules Window (under debugger, go to menu Debug -> Windows -> Modules)? It looks like it loads improper modules, maybe cached somewhere?

I heard about similar problem from my friend, he claimed it was caused by Resharper... Just in case you have it installed..

Comment: My Debug window doesn't have a "Modules" item.  I have:
*Immediate
*Breakpoints
*Output

I haven't installed Resharper.  I have ANTS5 memory profiler installed, but this problem began several days after setting that up.

Comment: PS, I updated the original post above, I've noticed that it's only changes in my XAML that aren't being updated.  I've added some debug code (i.e. Console.writeline("code here")) and these are being printed to the output window succesfully.  None of my UI changes in XAML are reflected, however.